# How to replace multiple keywords by corresponding keywords with the `replace` method?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I want to make a content editable div in which I replace explicit words with asterisks. This is my JavaScript code:

```js
function censorText(){
    var explicit = document.getElementById("textbox").innerHTML;
    var clean = explicit.replace(/"badtext1","cleantext1"|"badtext2","cleantext2"/);
    document.getElementById("textbox").innerHTML = clean;
}
```

Here’s the HTML for my `<div contenteditable>`:

```html
<div contenteditable="true" onkeyup="censorText()" id="textbox">Hello!</div>
```

As you can see, I tried using a regex operator to replace multiple strings at once, but it doesn’t work. It doesn’t replace `badtext2` with `cleantext2`, and it replaces `badtext1` with `0`. How can I make a single `.replace()` statement replace multiple strings?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

use `/.../g` to indicate a global replace.

```
var clean = explicit.replace(/badtext1/g,"cleantext2"/).replace(/cleantext1/g,"cleantext2"/).replace(/badtext2/g,"cleantext2"/);
```

Comment: You can also replace multiple strings with multiple other strings (at the same time), as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15604206/975097

Answer (score 11):

A generic way to handle this is as follows:

Establish a dictionary and build a regexp:

```
  var dictionary = { bad: 'good', worse: 'better', awful: 'wonderful'},
      regexp = RegExp ('\\b(' + Object.keys (dictionary).join ('|') + ')\\b', 'g');
```

The regexp is constructed from the dictionary key words (note they must not contain RegExp special characters).

Now do a replace, using a function in the place of the replacing string, the function simply return the value of the corresponding key.

```
  text = text.replace (regexp, function (_, word) { return dictionary[word]; });
```

The OP made no reference to upper/lower case. The following caters for initial and all caps and wraps the code as a function :

```
  function clean (text) {
    var dictionary = { bad: 'good', worse: 'better', awful: 'wonderful'},
        regexp = RegExp ('\\b(' + Object.keys (dictionary).join ('|') + ')\\b', 'ig');

    return text.replace (regexp, function (_, word) { 
      _ = dictionary[word.toLowerCase ()];
      if (/^[A-Z][a-z]/.test (word)) // initial caps
        _ = _.slice (0,1).toUpperCase () + _.slice (1);
      else if (/^[A-Z][A-Z]/.test (word)) // all caps
        _ = _.toUpperCase ();
      return _;
    });
  }
```

See the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/nJNq2/

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer from Jinzhao about covers it, but some other notes.
1) Don't use " in the RegEx
2) You can match multiple strings, but I think only replace to one value using a single RegEx.  The only way I can think of to match multiple is as Jinzhao has done.

The following code snippet seems to work for me:

```
function censorText(){             
    var explicit = document.getElementById("textbox").innerHTML;
    var clean = explicit.replace(/bad|worse/gi,"good");
     document.getElementById("textbox").innerHTML = clean;
}
```

The other issue I'm finding is that when a replace happens, it returns the cursor to the start of the text box, which is going to get frustrating.  If I find an answer to that, I'll post.